# What method should be used to determine when a function is zero when using a plotted graph?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I have a function $l(t) = 220 \sin(30 \pi t + \pi/6)$. I have plotted the function using the plot method.

I now have to find out when the current (l) equals zero. Having plotted the function, how do I use Mathematica to tell me when the current (l) equals zero?

The current (l) is the y-axis and time(t) is the x-axis.

For reference, the plotted function looks like this: [image]

Comment: `Solve[220 Sin[30 π t + π/6] == 0, t]` and hence ${-\pi + 12 \pi k \over 180 \pi}$ for $k$ and integer.  Incidentally, never *ever* use $I$ as a variable, since it is a constant in *Mathematica* ($I = \sqrt{-1}$).

Comment: Thank you! And yes, I didn't use I as the variable in the code, I used y.

Comment: So... doesn't my answer suffice?

Comment: For this specific `Plot` you can include a constraint: `Solve[{220 Sin[30 Pi x + Pi/6] == 0, 0 <= x <= 2/15},  x]`

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Yes it does. I just forgot to mark it as the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Solve[220 Sin[30 π t + π/6] == 0, t]
```

Answer (score 2):

I post this just to illustrate:

- how to utilize solutions (and specify range)
- use of [`Mesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) and[`MeshFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) to visualize zeroes

  ```
  func[t_] := 220 Sin[30 Pi t + Pi/6]
  With[{roots = t /. Solve[{func[t] == 0, 0 < t < 2/15}, t]}, 
  Plot[func[t], {t, 0, 2/15}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]], 
  Epilog -> {Arrow[{{#, 150}, {#, 0}}] & /@ roots, 
  Text[Framed[#], {#, 150}, {0, -1}] & /@ roots}, Frame -> True]]
  ```

[image]